# Is there a possibility to work with Java Map list in google endpoint?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I want to have Java Map fields in my entity class like this:

```
private Map<String,Key <Employee>> employeeRequestsList = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String,Key <Employee>> employeeList = new HashMap<>();
```

for example:

```
@Entity
public class RelationsGroup {

    @Parent
    Key<ManagerManager> managerKey;
    @Id
    Long id;
    @Index
    private String managerEmail;

   private Map<String,Key <Employee>> employeeRequestsList = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String,Key <Employee>> employeeList = new HashMap<>();
...
```

but when i deploy, I get

��� 15, 2016 9:52:53 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload checkEndpointsServingStatusResult
SEVERE: Endpoints configuration not updated.  The app returned an error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate with it.

is there a possibility to work with map list in google endpoint?

Comment: You can use maps but you cannot use them as a parameter in your @ApiMethod (see supported parameter types here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types). I seriously doubt the two lines you show us are responsible for this error. I had this issue myself and it went away without the need to change anything, so it could be temporary.

Comment: @konqi: sorry, but when i commented this two lines in this RelationGroup class It deploys successfully. After i have uncommented this lines, and got  error again.

Comment: The problem here is not the map but the `Key` which although `Serializable` doesn't like to be serialized by cloud endpoints (just like `Ref`). You can work around this by defining a transformer (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#sample_endpoints_transformer_class) for this kind of map, or you can simply replace the `Key` with the `Long` value of the Employee.Id.

Comment: I became also think about using transformer.But you right about serializable, it work when i put                        @Serialize   private Map<String,Key <Employee>> employeeList = new HashMap<>();

Comment: @Serialize from import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Serialize;

Comment: My guess is that the only reason why `@Serialize` works, is because the Key is not a live reference anymore. So this would work for all entities that you load from the datastore but not for newly created entities. Therefor I wouldn't recommend to handle the problem this way.